# Moose attribute default used even though subclass overrides the attribute

Tags: perl, oop, moose

I'm tinkering with Moose as introduced in [Intermediate Perl](http://www.intermediateperl.com/). I have an abstract class `Animal` with a property `sound`. The default behaviour should be to complain that `sound` has to be defined in subclasses:

```
package Animal;
use namespace::autoclean;
use Moose;

has 'sound' => (
    is => 'ro',
    default => sub {
        confess shift, " needs to define sound!"
    }
);

1;
```

A subclass has to do nothing else than define `sound`:

```
package Horse;
use namespace::autoclean;
use Moose;

extends 'Animal';

sub sound { 'neigh' }

1;
```

But testing this with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Horse;

my $talking = Horse->new;
say "The horse says ", $talking->sound, '.';
```

results in

```
Horse=HASH(0x3029d30) needs to define sound!
```

If I replace the anonymous function in `Animal` with something simpler as in

```
has 'sound' => (
    is => 'ro',
    default => 'something generic',
);
```

things work fine. Why is that? Why is the default function executed even though I override it in the subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two things in play here:  How attributes are initialized and how accessors work.

Non-lazy ('eager') attributes are initialized when the class is instantiated.  That's why you can actually leave off the

```
say "The horse says ", $talking->sound, '.';
```

and get the same error.  If you make the attribute lazy, on the other hand, the error goes away.  And that leads us to the real reason:  the difference between attributes, accessors, and builders.

`Animal` has an attribute, `sound`, which is just a place that stores some data related to instances of the class.  Because `sound` was declared `ro`, `Animal` also has a method that acts as an accessor, confusingly also called `sound`.  If you call this accessor, it looks at the value of the attribute and gives it to you.

But this value exists independent of the accessor.  The accessor provides a way to get at the value, but the actual existence of the value is dependent on the attribute's builder.  In this case, the builder for the attribute is the anonymous method `sub { confess shift, " needs to define sound!" }`, and it will get run as soon as the attribute needs to have a value.

In fact, if you leave out the `is => 'ro'`, you will stop Moose from creating an accessor at all, and the error will still pop at construction time.  Because that's when your class builds the `sound` attribute.

When the attribute needs its value depends on whether you've declared it as lazy or not.  Eager attributes are given their values on object construction.  It doesn't matter if there's an accessor, the builder gets called when the object is created.  And in this case, the builder dies.

Lazy attributes are given their values the first time they are needed.  The default accessor tries to get the value of the attribute, which causes the builder to fire, which causes the script to die.  When you override `sound`, you replace the default accessor with one that doesn't call the builder and therefore doesn't die anymore.

Does that mean you should make the `sound` attribute lazy?  No, I don't think so.  There's better mechanisms available, depending on what exactly you are trying to assert.  If what you are trying to assert is that `Animal->sound` must be defined, you can use [`BUILD`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Construction.pod#BUILD) like so:

```
package Animal;
use namespace::autoclean;
use Moose;

has 'sound' => (is => 'ro');

sub BUILD {
    my ($self) = @_;

    confess "$self needs to define sound!"
        unless defined $self->sound;
}

1;
```

During object construction, each of the parent classes' `BUILD` methods gets called, which lets them make assertions about object state.

If, on the other hand, what you wanted to assert is that a subclass has to have overridden `sound`, it's better not to make `sound` an attribute at all.  Instead,

```
package Animal;
use namespace::autoclean;
use Moose;

sub sound {    
    confess "Abstract method `sound` called!";
}

1;
```

Comment: Great, but your paragraph starting *“But this value exists independent of the accessor”* could be clearer. I don't think it's obvious *why*  removing the readonly attribute would get rid of the accessor, and I don't think it's clear to the OP that he has specified a builder

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I think the example is overly simple and contrived to _require_ one or the other technique, I guess the book just wanted to show different options. I've started looking into [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1405/lib/Moose/Manual/Attributes.pod#Default_and_builder_methods) for builders, defaults et cetera, and your answer was definitely an excellent starting point.